# How to greet women in Arabic?

Tags: arabic, greetings

Normally we say "Assalam o Alaikum", but my sir said that for women we need to say "Assalam o Alaikuna". Is that right?

Comment: Alaikum = They (He/She), Alikuna = They Female, Alaika = He, Alaiki = She.

Comment: Well to give a short answer: Both are valid and approved, but grammatically and linguistically more correct is the 2nd one for a group of (only) women (female) (>2)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get it really right, then you need to say:

- To one woman: as-salāmu ʻalayki (or ʻalayk)
- To two women: as-salāmu ʻalaykumā
- To three or more women: as-salāmu ʻalaykunna (or ʻalaykunn)
- To a mixed group (men and women): as-salāmu ʻalaykum

Comment: is not plural used for single person for respect?

Comment: @qdinar, you inquired a useful query. Actually it is seen that in some or even many languages or cultures many people use the plural form instead on the single, in order to respect ... / But, to the best of my knowledge, now and then it is used in Arabic as well, BUT: less than other cultures. (in limited positions, I reckon)

Answer (score 1):

Even **"Assalam o Alaikum"** could be used for women, it is more convenient to use **"Assalam o Alaikun"** ( without the appended -a ); unless you want to say another thing else without stopping, then you can use **"Assalam o Alikuna** (oh mothers/sisters or something else)". I wish it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to greeting in Arabic (for females):

According to Arabic grammar, KOM is used for men, and Kon (Konna) is used for women. As a result if you’d like to use the correct grammatical shape of it, you ought to say “Assalam o Alaikon (Konna) which is written like the following phrase:

> السلام علیکن

---

Of course, there is another nice point, and it is related to singular and plural nouns. Actually “Kon” is related to plural noun (according to the correct Arabic grammar).

---

But is the singular noun it is writes:

> السلام علیک      / Assalam o Alaike (For female)

Comment: The "e" in "Alaike" is pronounced in English right? I just ask because this transliteration seems a bit strange to me, but correct from that point of view!

Comment: Yeah dear mate, I reckon so (AFAIK). (for woman) / Perhaps it can be deemed as a SAAKEN (as a sign which is not pronounce ...).

Answer (score 0):

بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم

Kum (کم) means plural you (‘men’ or 'men & women')
Kuna (کنَّ) means plural you (only women)

Yet in conversations it is common to say Alaikum, however if we are to speak with eloquence to an only women group, then say Alaikuna is more correct yet uncommon, especially in non-Arab dialogues.

Comment: kum/kuna doesn't mean plural but refers to plural!

Answer (score 0):

As much as I see, it can use for both men and women in informal form. But if you are looking for the formal form of the greeting or saying salam for women, you should be aware that if there are more than 2 women, you should say Assalamo Alaikon.

There is another important matter that you can note, and that is about two women. In fact if there are two women, you should say Assalamo alaikoma in the form of formal and in fact according to the true grammar of Arabic.